# Fusioncharts timeseries transparent background

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, fusioncharts

I am trying to make the background of a FusionCharts time-series chart transparent. I have tried the usual attributes that work with other chart types, and also hardcoded a background colour, but those chart attributes don't seem to apply to time-series charts. I have searched the documentation but cannot find anything useful for the time-series chart type. Is this possible, or with a CSS workaround? When I inspect the chart svg the `opacity` on all the elements within it are all `undefined`.

e.g. `<rect transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" height="150" width="403" fill="#ffffff" opacity="undefined"></rect>`

```
chart: {
    bgColor: "#1d1b41",
    bgAlpha: "0",
    canvasBgAlpha: "0"
}
```

Sandbox: [time-series chart](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-cherry-v0zyhq?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transparency can be set only through CSS at the moment. Not sure if their time-series graphs have a bug that is preventing the transparency being set through the chart properties, or if it's simply not supported for this graph type. Regardless, the fix is to select the `rect` element within the time-series graph `svg` element and set the `fill` to be transparent:

```
svg rect {
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```